# CardAction and message shown (node.js SDK - skype channel)

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using the Node.js SDK to create a bot for skype, using the microsoft bot framework.

I am experimenting few different behaviors and I am having some problems.

For example, I have created a set of ThumbNails cards with image, text and 3 buttons each. One button open a web page. The other two are used in a Prompt.choice to proceed in the conversation.
The problem is that I believe I need to show the label for the prompt to work.
Is that correct?
Because the label might be long / or it might not make any sense for the user to see again what he pressed.

I try to paste some code to try and explain better:

```
bot.dialog('/mydialog', [
    function (session) {
    // Ask the user to select an item from a carousel.
    var msg = new builder.Message(session)
        .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
        .attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel)
        .attachments([
            new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
                .title("Card number 1")
                .text("Description first card")
              .images([
                builder.CardImage.create(session, "https://www.example.org/img1.gif")
                      .tap(builder.CardAction.showImage(session, "ttps://www.example.org/img1.gif")),
             ])
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, "https://google.com", "Website"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "select:100", "button 1"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "select:101", "Button2")

                ]),
            new builder.ThumbnailCard(session)
                .title("Card 2")
                .text("Description card 2")
                .images([
                    builder.CardImage.create(session, "https://image.jpg")
                        .tap(builder.CardAction.showImage(session, "https://image.jpg")),
                ])
                .buttons([
                    builder.CardAction.openUrl(session, "https://google.com", "Website"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "select:200", "button3"),
                    builder.CardAction.imBack(session, "select:201", "button4")
                ]),
           ]);

    builder.Prompts.choice(session, msg, "select:100|select:101|select:200|select:201");
 },
function (session, results) {
    var action, item;
    var kvPair = results.response.entity.split(':');
    switch (kvPair[0]) {
        case 'select':
            action = 'selected';
            break;
    }
    switch (kvPair[1]) {
        case '100':
            item ="/dialog1";
            break;
        case '101':
            item ="/dialog2";
            break;
        case '200':
            item ="/dialog3";
            break;
        case '201':
            item ="/dialog4";
            break;

    }

           session.beginDialog(item);
} 

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be better to use dialog actions. As a button in a card is pressed it will start a corresponding dialog. After it has finished, it will return to the current dialog. Note that you can press buttons in the cards at any moment after it was displayed. So, it may happen at any time that is why dialog actions is a better choice here.

```
bot.beginDialogAction("select:100:action:just:unique:name", 
      "/dialog1", { matches: "select:100"});
bot.beginDialogAction("select:101:action:just:unique:name", 
      "/dialog2", { matches: "select:101"});
// and so on.
```

Note that if you don't want to `select:100` is displayed in the chat, you may use
`builder.CardAction.postBack` instead of `imBack` (not supported on all platforms).

Comment: hi Sergey, thanks a lot for your answer.
You are right saying that it can be pressed anytime, so that might be a problem.

Comment: Problem is that they want the button inside the card.. I will try the postBack as suggested, thanks!